# Keeping only distinct values in tables using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, merge, in-place

I am storing a relatively complex immutable object in a database. There are many many-to-one associations - the object has properties that have properties and so on.

I would like to have each object stored only once, based on a business key that is in this case every single property of the object.

The workflow is like this:

- user creates a complex object. This can take a long time, code is all scattered over the place.
- I query the database, to see if the exact same object was already stored before:

  - if not, `save`
  - if yes, set the object's id and `merge`

The problem is that Hibernate's `merge` has quite inconvenient semantics:

```
transientObject = createComplexTransientObject();
mergedObject = session.merge(transientObject);
// here you have to discard transientObject
// use mergedObject from now on
```

The object that got created has to be discarded and replaced with the one provided by Hibernate, which means I have to update all references to it.

I need a way to tell hibernate: "This completely new transientObject appears to be identical to one that is already in the database. Merge it in place." In other words:

```
object = createComplexTransientObject();
session.inPlaceMerge(object);
// object is now persistent
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe saveOrUpdate does exactly what you want. But its behavior also depends on your mapping.

If you do saveOrUpdate, does it give you the results you expect?

---

A bit off-topic here: do you know about Query By Example? http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-examples

---

Never mind. I just see this question is two years old. Stupid 'related questions'-option of stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes, I know of Query By Example. I think QBE would create another object based on my query, so I have my original object and a result of the query... I would like to have the original object alone.

Comment: I have to investigate saveOrUpdate. Maybe if my mapping is smart enough to declare the business key as all fields of the object, when I run a save, it would get assigned an id in place... I need to try that!